# Characteristic equation of a delay differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

Is it possible to find the characteristic equation of the following DDE using Mathematica

```
x''[t] == \[Epsilon] (a*D[BesselJ[1, x[t - \[Tau]]], t]) - x[t]
```

a=2.5, [Epsilon] =.014

Comment: Because the DDE is nonlinear, it may not have a characteristic equation.